# mod_wsgi && virtualenvwrapper && python executable

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm on a virtualhost with no access to the apache httpd.conf, there is no system virtualenv configuration, I've installed and set up one virtualenv on my home, it's possible to run the virtualenv's python interpreter as my user, instead of apache's nobody??

What i'm really searching with this, is write permissions in my home...

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of separate questions here.  You should either summarize your problem into a single question "How do I do X?" or separate each concern into different question posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two modes that mod_wsgi can run in, embedded mode and daemon mode. If they have set you up to run in embedded mode and this is a shared system, that is a bad idea. They should instead be looking at daemon mode. When running daemon mode the user/group of the process can be overridden.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess

You can check whether you are running under embedded or daemon mode by doing the check:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode

---

UPDATE 1

Also go read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/python-interpreter-is-not-created-for.html
  http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

No an interpreter is not created per request. Read the above and that may help to clarify things.

Comment: Thanks!, so, in the environment described in the question, in embedded, everytime that anybody loads the script url, a whole new python interprter is loaded in memory, and the library stuff too, this for every python/mod_wsgi script the users set up in the system ???